# Proper way to make this scoring system?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on a game for iOS and I was wondering why this countdown won't work. I want to have a set amount of moves per level in this game, and I want it to subtract 1 move every time the user taps on one of the puzzle pieces.

This is the bit of code I've set up:

1. I set up two integers in the header file: `int movesRemaining;` and `int moved;`
2. The `SKLabelNode` that displays the amount of moves:

   ```
   moves = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"DIN Condensed"];
   moves.position = CGPointMake(110, -15);
   moves.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MOVES %d", movesRemaining];
   moves.fontSize = 25;
   moves.zPosition = 2.0;
   moves.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];

   [menuBar addChild:moves];
   ```
3. The method that calculates the score:

   ```
   -(void)moves {
   movesRemaining = 4;
   movesRemaining = (movesRemaining - moved);
   ```

   }
4. The code that tells movesRemaining to subtract 1 move each time the puzzle is touched:

   ```
   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
   SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

   if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"sq1"]) {
       [_BS1 removeFromParent];
       moved = 1;
   }
   if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"sq2"]) {
       [_BS2 removeFromParent];
       moved = 1;
   }
   if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"sq3"]) {
       [_BS3 removeFromParent];
       moved = 1;
   }
   if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"sq4"]) {
       [_BS4 removeFromParent];
       moved = 1;
   }
   if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"sq5"]) {
       [_BS5 removeFromParent];
       moved = 1;
   }
   ```

**My question is where did I go wrong that it doesn't subtract 1 each time the puzzle is tapped? How can I properly make movesRemaining subtract 1 each time the user touches the puzzle piece?**

If more information is needed please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Make moved: moved = moved - 1;

Comment: where do u call [self moves];?

Comment: Also, where do u update the text on the label?

Comment: Right at the beginning of the initWithSize method @akashg and the label is also in the initWithSize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that it isn't being updated. How to fix:

Touches: 
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"sq1"]) {
    movesRemaining = movesRemaining - 1;
    [_BS1 removeFromParent];
}
```

1. Take out the stuff in the initWithSize method and add this to your `-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime` method:

   ```
   if (!moves) {
   moves = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"DIN Condensed"];
   moves.position = CGPointMake(110, -15);
   moves.fontSize = 25;
   moves.zPosition = 2.0;
   moves.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
   [menuBar addChild:moves];
   ```

   }

   //scoring
   moves.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MOVES %d", movesRemaining];

This will fix your code. It will then update every time it is tapped like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Move `movesRemaining = 4;` to the `init` method.
Then add `[self moves];` to the end of `-(void)touchesBegan`.

Comment: then add `[self moves];` to the end of `-(void)touchesBegan`

Answer (score 0):

In the moved method change it so that it declares moved = moved - 1; then that will add the rolling effect

Comment: This didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

```
moves = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"DIN Condensed"];
moves.position = CGPointMake(110, -15);
moves.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MOVES %d", movesRemaining];
moves.fontSize = 25;
moves.zPosition = 2.0;
moves.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
movesRemaining = 4; //Move initial movesRemaining value here.
[menuBar addChild:moves];


-(void)moves { //Subtract number of moves everytime the user moves.
movesRemaining = (movesRemaining - moved);
}
```

Comment: Still not changing :(